# How can I write this php code to get only the specific information?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just cannot figure this out. Let's say I have an appointment tool to schedule appointments. For every appointment I have an additonal form that shows certain information specific to only that appointment.

Now when a user clicks a button called form it takes them to an additional page on this additional page I want to show another list of appointments but only that have the same name as the one that was clicked on.

In the appointments table in the database the names are stored in lep. The first php code I have provided gets the name for only the selected appointment. The second code provided get's all the appointments. I have attached some screenshots that hopefully prove helpful.

How can I get only the appointments where the lep is the same as the lep that comes from the first code?

```
<?php
    require "id.php";
    require "calendarconnect.php";

        //MySqli Select Query
        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT lep FROM appointments WHERE ID = $contactid");

            while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

            echo $line['lep'];}

    require "freeclose.php";
?>


<?php

        require "calendarconnect.php";

    //MySqli Select Query

    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT ID, appointmentdate, appointmenttime, nature, doctorname, lep FROM appointments ORDER BY appointmentdate");

    print '<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3" border="1" class="sortable">';
    print '<tr><th>Date/Time</th><th>Nature</th><th>Doctor Name</th><th>Actions</th></tr>';
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        print '<tr>';
        print "<td>" . date("m-d-y", strtotime($row['appointmentdate'])) . "&nbsp;"  .date( "g:i A",strtotime($row['appointmenttime'] )). "</td>";
        print '<td>'.$row["nature"].'</td>';
        print '<td>'.$row["doctorname"].'</td>';
        print "<td><a href=\"index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=18&cd=" . $row['ID'] . "\">Edit&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a>";
print "<a href=\"appointmentdelete.php?id=" . $row['ID'] . "\"onclick=
      \"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";
        print '</tr>';
    }  
    print '</table>';

    require "freeclose.php";
?>
```

[image: Appointment]

[image: Appointment's from form]

[image: LEP]

Comment: add the id to what ever is clicked on, and check that to decide what to show

Comment: @Dagon I have tried that but that will only show one appointment instead of all appointments that have the same name of the one that was clicked. The id is that of the appointment because there's other information I grab also.

Comment: no idea of your db schema so can only answer in the most broad terms

Comment: @MarquiseR You probably will want to have a LEP table each LEP has their own row. Then you could do a foreign key to the id of that person inserted into a column of whatever table this is. That way, you can keep track of LEP by client id. Otherwise you have to search by name, which will be a nightmare, especially if that is the ONLY way to find the same person in a table.

Comment: @Rasclatt That sounds like a good idea I will look into doing that. As it stands now that will be quite difficult to implement since the information is stored in separate databases. This seems more advanced than my expertise.